# Calling a generic method from IronRuby

Tags: .net, methods, generics, ironruby

How can I call a generic method (.NET 3.5 SP1) from IronRuby v0.9?
Trying to do something as `obj.method(:method_name).of(String).call` seems not to work as "of" is an unknown method.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me (I'm using 0.9.1):

IronRuby:

```
obj = ClassLibrary1::Class1.new
obj.method(:test).of(String).call("test")
```

C#:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Test<T>(T param)
        {
            return param.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, this seems to be an issue with the v0.9 release (http://dlr.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=20378).
If I compile the 0.9.1 release myself, it works for me as well.

Comment: The 0.9.1 binary release is out now, so you don't need to compile it yourself

Answer (score 2):

You can also use array indexers to pass generic arguments to methods, and you can execute a proc with array indexers as well, so Shay's example can look like this too:

```
obj.method(:test)[String]["test"]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me Jimmy. obj.method(:test)[String] returns a String object - 'String', so passing ["test"] to it results in an exception.